# In powerdot changed colors are always active and do not take the iacolor when they are inactive

Tags: powerdot

In the following example you see a listing with itemize type 1. The changed color in the text (red) and the changed color of the items (orange) do not take the `iacolor` when they are inactive.

How can I give to the inactive changed colors also the color of `iacolor` when they are not active?

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\color{orange}\ensuremath\bullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\color{orange}\ensuremath\bullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\color{orange}\ensuremath\bullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\color{orange}\ensuremath\bullet}

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{titletxt}
\begin{itemize}[type=1]
\item<1-> txt A
\item<2-> txt B1 {\color{red}{txt B2}} txt B3
\item<3-> txt C {\color{red}{txt C2}} txt B3
\item<4-> txt D
\end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to define a command to switch the color only on the specified overlay, print the text on every overlay, and switch the color back on the specified overlay.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\color{orange}\ensuremath\bullet}

\newcommand{\clactive}[3]{%
\onslide*{#1}{\color{#2}}%
#3 %
\onslide*{#1}{\color{pdcolor1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{titletxt}
\begin{itemize}[type=1]
\item<1-> txt A
\item<2-> txt B1 \clactive{2-}{red}{txt B2} txt B3
\item<3-> txt C \clactive{3-}{red}{txt C2} txt C3
\item<4-> txt D
\end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Marijn for the given solution. Now I tried to find a possibility to reach the same effect for the color of the item bullets, but I had no succes.

Have you any suggestion?